# Telegram command starts whenever another person starts it

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

So I don't know how to properly ask this question so it might seem kind of off, sorry about that.

I made a telegram bot that gets some images from a website and send it to your chat. However when an user calls the command the photos are also sent to the other users that have started the bot.

For instance, If User A calls the command to get the photos the bot will send it to him as well as to User B, User C and User D, all stacking together as if it were a single call to everyone using the bot

```
import requests
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse
import re
import telebot
API_KEY = os.getenv("API_KEY")
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)



url_mainpage = "https://url.com"

soup = bs(requests.get(url_mainpage).content, "html.parser")
full_link = soup.find("h5", class_="elementor-image-box-title")

selectlist = full_link.select(".elementor-image-box-title a")
for a in selectlist:
    global lastchapterlink
    lastchapterlink = a['href']

images = []
stripped_images = []


def download_last_chapter():
    soup = bs(requests.get(lastchapterlink).content, "html.parser")
    images_link = soup.findAll("img")

    for img in images_link:
        images.append(img.get("src"))
    for link in images:
        stripped_images.append(link.strip())
    print(stripped_images)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["last_chapter"])
def send_images(message):
    download_last_chapter()
    for telegram_send in stripped_images:
        try:
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo = telegram_send)
        except:
            None

bot.polling()
```

this is the part of the code containing the bot

Comment: You are probably storing a list of all the users who called the bot, but there's not enough code here to figure out the bug.

Comment: That's literally all the code that uses the telegram API. However I'll add the complete code since it's not that big either anyways

Answer (score 0):

Per the [API documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_photo), the bot will reply in whatever channel it sees the message in. Are your users DMing it, or posting in a shared channel that you're all part of? Also, you're not clearing stripped_images between calls-- you're just appending the new images to it.

Comment: Nop, they aren't DMing it nor posting in a shared channel. And sorry I'm new to this and can't understand what you mean with clearing between calls the stripped_images list